# Returning either a Partial View or a View

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

From my Home page i have a search textbox that when search is clicked calls an ajax search function which calls my controller. Based on the searchString that is passed I want to either replace a div with a gridview (this part is working) or have it load a new page. Instead it is loading the new view in the same div that the partial views are replacing. How can I do this? Ill post my code below.
All my data is coming back correctly and everything else is working just fine.

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        $('.search').click(function () {
            var $buttonClicked = $(this);
            var searchString = $("#searchStringTextBox").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ShowGrids")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { searchString: searchString },
                modal: true,
                success: function (partialView) {
                    $('#gridViews').html(partialView);
                    $('#gridViews').show();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

controller

```
public ActionResult ShowGrids(string searchString)
    {
        if (IsValidPersonIdFormat(searchString))
        {
            var id = searchString.Substring(1);
            id = id.Replace("-", "");
            var x = Convert.ToInt64(id);
            var model = cs.GetById(x);
            TempData["model"] = model;
            return Redirect(Url.Action("ShowPersonDetails", "Data"));
        }
        else if(IsValidIdFormat(searchString))
        {
            var id = searchString.Substring(1);
            id = id.Replace("-", "");
            var model = ps.GetById(Convert.ToInt64(id));
            return View("Details", model);
        }
        else if (IsValidServiceIdFormat(searchString))
        {
            var id = searchString.Substring(1);
            id = id.Replace("-", "");
            var model = vss.GetById(Convert.ToInt64(id));
            return PartialView("ServiceDetails", model);
        }
}

   public ActionResult ShowPersonDetails()
    {
        var model = TempData["model"];
        return View("PersonDetails", model);
    }
```

This has every way I tried to get it to work. Just figured I would show what I was trying and it not working.

Comment: ``RedirecToAction`` will not work in ajax call case, return url as string and redirect to url using javascript/jquery

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention, there are examples of all methods i tried to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. This is not fully tested.

```
public JsonResult ShowGrids(string searchString)
{
        if (IsValidPersonIdFormat(searchString))
        {
            var id = searchString.Substring(1);
            id = id.Replace("-", "");
            var x = Convert.ToInt64(id);
            var model = cs.GetById(x);
            TempData["model"] = model;
            return Json(new { IsRedirect = true, RedirectUrl = Url.Action("ShowPersonDetails", "Data") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else if(IsValidIdFormat(searchString))
        {
            var id = searchString.Substring(1);
            id = id.Replace("-", "");
            var model = ps.GetById(Convert.ToInt64(id));
            return Json(new { IsRedirect = false, Content = RenderRazorViewToString("Details", model) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else if (IsValidServiceIdFormat(searchString))
        {
            var id = searchString.Substring(1);
            id = id.Replace("-", "");
            var model = vss.GetById(Convert.ToInt64(id));
            return Json(new { IsRedirect = false, Content = RenderRazorViewToString("ServiceDetails", model) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}

<script>

    $(function () {
        $('.search').click(function () {
            var $buttonClicked = $(this);
            var searchString = $("#searchStringTextBox").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ShowGrids")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { searchString: searchString },
                modal: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data.IsRedirect){
                        window.location.href = data.RedirectUrl;
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#gridViews').html(data.Content);
                        $('#gridViews').show();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Code for rendering view to string:

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
  ViewData.Model = model;
  using (var sw = new StringWriter())
  {
    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                             viewName);
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                 ViewData, TempData, sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
    viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
    return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay so I tihnk this is exactly what the way I want to do this but it didnt quite work. But i dont think the If statement in the javascript is working correctly, and I say that because it still loads my views in the place of the div.

Comment: @Darkwingduck It should not load the view because it's in the `if else` block. Debug to see if `data.IsRedirect` is true or false. Also, put `return;` at end of `window.location.href = data.RedirectUrl;`

Comment: I got this to work, but I had to add    
    `public ActionResult Details()
        {
            long x = Convert.ToInt64(TempData["id"]);
            var model = cs.GetById(x);
            if (model != null)
            {
                return View("Details", model);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Home");
            }
        }`

Answer (score 2):

The `if` on server-side is not affecting what the javascript does on success: it's stuffing the results of the call into a div.

If that's not what you want to do, you need to test for the results in javascript and do something else if what you got is not a partial view.

Comment: I figured it would have something to do with that but I dont really know how to go about it. Do you know of any examples I could look at?

Comment: Not offhand. You could return a URL in the case of trying to redirect, test for that in the success method (result starts with http, eg), and change the window location instead of modifying the div contents.

Comment: Well somtimes I do want to modify the contents of the div. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Just test for a url before modifying - have an in the success method that decides whether to change location or to modify the div

Answer (score 1):

make sure when ever you call action using jQuery, action will return HTML string into jQuery, if you want to redirect than return some json string from your action to jQuery call and redirect page from there